# React Native - Mismatch in steps between getDailyStepCountSamples and Google Fit App

Tags: android, react-native, google-fit

#### Problem

When I call `GoogleFit.getDailyStepCountSamples()` to retrieve steps, I receive a step count that significantly lower than that shown in the Google Fit app.

#### Dev Environment

MacOS Big Sur
React Native 0.63.3
Android Simulator - Nexus 5 API 19

#### Steps to Replicate

Set your step options and call the function. The code would look something like the following

```
const stepsOpt = {
    startDate: '2021-09-15T00:00:00.000Z', // the start of the day in question
    endDate: new Date().toISOString(), // you could also set this to the end of the day
    bucketUnit: 'MINUTE',
    bucketInterval: 1
}
  
const res = await GoogleFit.getDailyStepCountSamples(stepsOpt)
console.log(`\n\nMy step data is\n${JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)}\n\n`)
```

In the resulting log, observe data from any `com.google.android.gms` source. Look at the total steps, and the rawSteps.
Compare this with the total number of steps shown in the Google Fit app for the same day (Can be found by opening the **Google Fit app** -> **Home** -> **Trends/Steps** -> **Day** -> **See source data**)

#### What I Observe

There is a mismatch between both the total steps and the rawSteps

#### What I Expected

- To see a match between the total steps
- To see some matches in the rawStep data

#### Screenshot

On the left is a screenshot of log after running my code. The right is a screenshot of the raw data according to the Google Fit app.

[image: mismatch in steps data]

Answer (score 0):

In short, if it's a sync issue, there is nothing you can do about, you just have to wait.

If it's caused by data is only taken from local device storage.
Or parts of data in `Google Fit app` is from other apps, these two need to be investigated and reproduced.

https://developers.google.com/fit/faq#how_do_i_get_the_same_values_step_count_calories_distance_etc_as_the_google_fit_app